# Problems with getting a 1x1 transparent PNG pixel in Python with pytracking

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-email, tracking

I am using pytracking module trying to receive my pixel so that I can add it to my html-code.

I use the following code:

```
import pytracking

(pixel_byte_string, mime_type) = pytracking.get_open_tracking_pixel()

print(pixel_byte_string, mime_type)
```

When using the print statement, I get the following:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08\x04\x00\x00\x00\xb5\x1c\x0c\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0bIDATx\xdacd`\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x020\x81\xd0/\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82' image/png
```

How do I get the pixel in the correct format to add it to my HTML-code? I'm lost here.